# How do I make a Grails criteria execute as a left join?

Tags: grails, criteria

I have a Grails criteria that has associated children classes that are nullable. I need to get all results, even those with null children, but the criteria gets executed with an INNER JOIN. How do I get it to be executed with a LEFT JOIN?

Grails version is 1.3.7 (most recent), query is being executed via createCriteria().list

Comment: What version of Grails? Also, how are you executing the query? Using dynamic finders? createCriteria? executeQuery?

Comment: Grails version is 1.3.7 (most recent), query is being executed via createCriteria().list

Comment: I have merged your accounts and you are now re-united with your question.

Answer (score 2):

As question is old and lot of improvement has been done on this. Following will help someone searching like me.. Following works even with complex and{} and or{} blocks inside criteria query with collections. in eg. specialities is a collection.

```
    List users = User.createCriteria().list(){
                    createAlias('specialities', 'sp', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

    ilike("sp.name","%"+trimPhrase+"%")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use a hql statement. for left joins see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

hql statements can be performed as follows: DomainClass.executeQuery("select from ....")

Comment: I really need to use criteria for this due to other business requirements. I have tried to use `createAlias("childClass", "child", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)` but I think I ran into [this Grails bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7324). Still pulling my hairs over this.

Comment: i would recommend to do it with hql, because you have more control about the join mechanism